# javafx: when the completion of a drag and drop operation triggers a "long" task, the d&d icon persists on the target

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, javafx

As in the title, the user drops a file on the target. This should trigger an operation that is not quite immediate , say it takes 4 seconds. 
***The problem is that the icon used by the system to represent the dragged item stays on the window till the operation is completed and the `void handle(DragEvent d)` event returns.***

[image: The icon that freezes]

This is perceived by the user as an application "freezing". We know that the application ever takes 4 seconds to process the dropped item, but this would probably not be noticed at all by the user if the icon disappeared immediately *after* the user releases the item on the target and *before* the 4 seconds operation started.

Here is the code relevant for dropping:

```
s.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override  public void handle(DragEvent t) {

            //1. The drop is OK
            t.setDropCompleted(true);

            //<--I THINK THAT SOMETHING SHOULD BE PUT HERE TO FORCE D&D TO REMOVE THE ICON

            //2. let's start an elaboration that involves the files
            //   that have been dropped!
            try { Thread.sleep(4000); } catch (InterruptedException ignore_exception_in_test) {}

        }
    });
```

Are there any options to address this problem?

The complete code, if you just want to reproduce the case; just fix imports and drop a file from Explorer into the stage.

```
public class ShortSelfCompilableExample01 extends Application {

Stage stage;

@Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    stage.setTitle("Drag&Drop test");

    this.stage = stage;

    Scene s = new Scene(new BorderPane());

    stage.setScene(s);

    s.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override  public void handle(DragEvent t) {

            //1. Ok, the drop is OK
            t.setDropCompleted(true);
            //2. let's start an elaboration that involves the files
            //   that have been dropped!
            try {
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore_exception_in_test_environments) {}

        }
    });

    s.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent> () {
        @Override public void handle(DragEvent t) {
            t.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
        }
    });

    stage.show();

}
}
```

**PS. Why I didn't use a thread**
The "first class" solution for responsive UIs is to use a thread.
But this is not a background task with very long execution time. This should last in the worst case 5 seconds, while threading introduces a certain degree of complexity.
The shorter is the lenght of the operation, the less is convenient introduce a thread just to "smooth" the UI.

Answer (score 3):

Why this happens: the problem is in the design of the DnD. It depends on the platform, but in general the OS invokes some method which is that propagates up to JavaFX and ends up in your event handler. This method should return a result of the DnD operation so that the OS could know what to do. So it is synchronous by design.

What to do: your proposal with using another thread is probably the only way to handle this problem. It should be quite simple: get all the info needed for the long operation in the event handler, start a new thread, make the long operation there and update the UI using `Platform.runLater`

Comment: I agree. See also my comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381625/javafx-alert-popup-after-drag-and-drop-action-casues-frozen-drop-icon