# JavaFX: Alert popup after drag-and-drop action casues frozen drop icon

Tags: java, javafx, popup, alert

Using JavaFX 8 I'm experiencing a specific drag-and-drop problem:

The confirmation popup after dropping gets the icon stuck on screen when a drag is released, even overlaying the Alert dialog itself like so:

[image]
<sub>(source: [image.ibb.co](https://image.ibb.co/e71dQL/overlay.jpg))</sub>

The text "copy" and the icon remain stuck until user closes the popup.

This is the minimal code to reproduce the problem. To test, run this program and drag any file (ex. from Desktop) into the app window:

```
public class Main extends Application {

private Parent root = new VBox();

private void onDragOver(DragEvent dragEvent) {
    if (dragEvent.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
        dragEvent.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
    }
}

private void isUserSure() {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING,"",ButtonType.OK);
    alert.showAndWait();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    root.setOnDragOver((event) -> onDragOver(event));
    root.setOnDragDropped((event) -> isUserSure());
    primaryStage.setTitle("ghost demo");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: I do not guarantee this will work but try to empty the DragView: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/Dragboard.html#setDragView-javafx.scene.image.Image-
I searched `javafx clear ghost drag` on Google

Comment: @Dom No joy, I tried, but thanks anyway. The doc says this "This method should be called only when starting drag and drop operation in the DRAG_DETECTED handler, calling it at other times doesn't have any effect."

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @kleopatra, I've cleaned my question to the best of my ability.

Comment: hmm ... can't reproduce: worksforme in fx8 and fx11 on win10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it myself by doing the following:

Knowing that Modal Dialogs (Warning popups etc.) essentially "block" every other Stage via a call to `showAndwait()` the problem must be that this also blocks the `dragEvent` from finishing in the onDragDropped method (set via lambda in `setOnDragDropped`).

Make sure you wrap the call to your popup method and the stuff that is to happen to the actual dropped items in a `Platform.runLater()`

This will let the `dragEvent` stuff finish first. Observe the change I made in the following line of method `start`:

```
root.setOnDragDropped((event) -> Platform.runLater(() -> isUserSure()));
```

Make sure you don't wrap more than you have to, otherwise the items in the `Dragboard` will go out of scope. Extraction of needed items from `Dragboard` has to happen at the time of drop, and not inside `runLater()`

Comment: Did not work. runLater does nothing if called from FxThread.

Answer (score 0):

To make it working, the runLater must be started from a secondary thread :

```
root.setOnDragDropped((event) -> {
 Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                    interruptedException.printStackTrace();
                }
                Platform.runLater(() ->Platform.runLater(() -> isUserSure(););
            });
            t.run();
);
```

Comment: Thanks. For me, this approach works in general (JavaFX 17). I simplified the whole to `new Thread(() -> Platform.runLater(() -> doSomething())).start();`. I also needed to decouple the data supplied by the Dragboard in advance.